# A phone call you ask your friend to make to you in middle of a date

Tags: expressions

Is there a dedicated expression for a pre-arranged phone call you receive to give you an opportunity to politely get out of a situation (e.g. a dinner date)?

Comment: How do you "make a phone call **to** someone"?

Comment: English is my second language but that sounds about right to me. What grammar rule am I breaking here?

Comment: I don't think you are breaking any particular rule of English grammar, not exactly. Maybe just one of usage. It just does not sound right to "make a call to someone"; rather, you simply call someone.  Somehow your set of words doesn't work right together, and I'm not sure I can clearly express why. It just comes down to that it sounds very unnatural to say that you would "make" a call "to" someone. You just call them.

Comment: @tchrist "Make a (phone) call *to* someone" is perfectly acceptable in BrE. I would either "call X" or "make a call *to* X".

Comment: @tchrist I see. Since you're referring to the the title, I have to agree that it sounds a little mechanical and unnatural. I kind of rushed it.

Comment: Date extraction call. 'Bad date rescue call' is on the web.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More generally, I'd call it an *escape- plan/valve/hatch*.

Comment: So, *escape call* then?

Comment: Yeah. That seems to work. Might need a hyphen.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, these guys call it a [*'get out' call*](http://getoutcall.com/).

Comment: Which 'these guy's?

Comment: @Mitch, the ones who made the getoutcall.com website.

Comment: Please make the answer self contained. Explain what this other site means by get out call. @JanusBahsJacquet: Oh, right, I wasn't following the link.

Answer (score 1):

I think the term **parachute call** was used in a movie I watched recently. Does that ring a bell (heh, heh) for anyone else?

Comment: I can't see anything with this meaning on Google. Would be good to have a reference to someone using this.